# How to compile sqlite by C++Builder for MacOS X

Tags: c++, sqlite, c++builder

The sqlite database is compiled easily by C++Builder on Win32 platform.

Has anybody ever compiled it by C++Builder on Mac?

I tried to compile it by defining conditional macro **SQLITE_OS_UNIX** but it causes some errors, the errors and type of errors are not important. The matter is that whether it is possible or not, If it is possible, with which conditional macros?

Does anybody have experience with this case?

Comment: For example at this line :  int rc = flock(pFile->h, LOCK_UN); => error : "Declaration is not allowed here" ; Description: In C language all variables should be defined at begining of function; in sqlite3.c It has not observed. If I correct this issue, a lot of other errors are occured. I don't intend to compile the source with  dispelling errors. because sqlite has a big source and this process need hard working. I expect to compile it as It be compiled on Win32 (easily and without errors).

Comment: It sounds like you need to ensure you're compiling with `cc -std=c99` if not `-std=c11`; the complaint is one that C89 compilers give when a declaration comes in the middle of block of code. C++ has allowed that for ages; C has allowed it since C99. MSVC must be treating the code more or less as C++ since it is a C89 compiler and in C mode does complain about it. To say "the errors and the type of errors are not important" is to say "I don't care whether it compiles on Mac OS X or not". The errors are crucial to the problem. What is C++ Builder, anyway? Which compilation system are you using?

Comment: Which code are you using?  I just downloaded [SQLite 3.8.0.2](http://sqlite.org/) (the file `sqlite-autoconf-3080002.tar.gz`) and extracted it, configured it and compiled it without any problem.  Are you trying to take the code from a Windows source distribution and build that on Mac OS X?  That is likely to be a harder proposition.

Comment: @mhtaqia This line is not part of a recent SQLite (and you haven't even told us the version you are using). Try the [current version](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), or nobody else will be able to reproduce this.

Comment: Thanks to CL and Jonathan Leffler. Good information was commented.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: How do you compile sqlite in Mac? With which command line? I tried ./configure; make; make install but was not successful and some errors occured. (I have downloaded sqlite-autoconf-3080002.tar.gz)

Comment: It compiled successfuly. thanks.